# Non-polynomial difference: $T(n) = 2T(n/2) + n \log n$?

Tags: algorithms

It is said that we can not apply Master Theorem to $T(n) = aT(n/b) + f(n)$ if there is a non-polynomial difference between $f(n)$ and $n^{\log_{b}a}$. Polynomial difference means: $f(n) / n^{\log_{b}(a)} = n^{c}$ for any real number c. However, in $T(n) = 2T(n/2) + n \log n$, $f(n) / n^{\log_{b}a} = \log n$ which is not $n^c$, right? That means there's non-polynomial difference, right? Then why can we apply MT to this expression?

PLEASE PLEASE NOTE: I am not asking about $T(n) = 2T(n/2) + n/\log n$. I am asking about $T(n) = 2T(n/2) + n \log n$ and I want to know whether $f(n) / n^{\log_{b}a} = \log n = n^c$.

Comment: Hint: The condition on $f(n)$ should be polynomially *bounded* growth function. Please review the statement of the master theorem and the definition of polynomially bounded.

Comment: Research is done before I ask the question. MT: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem      . Polynomial Bounded: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/336374/what-does-it-mean-for-a-function-to-be-polynomially-bounded   Please tell me where I can find the answer, thx.

Comment: "Please tell me where I can find the answer" Maybe the shortest route is to forget the so-called M****r theorem and to consider $$t_k=2^{-k}T(2^k)$$ then $$t_k=t_{k-1}+k\log2$$ hence $$t_k=t_0+\log2\sum_{i=1}^ki=\Theta(k^2)$$ that is, $$T(n)=\Theta(n(\log n)^2)$$ You see, no mysteries, no cases, no nothing except mathematics... :-)